# Understanding diffraction using Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, diffraction

When light falls on a slit, I can take the width of the slit as the maximum uncertainty in position of the photons as they pass through the slit. So I know $\Delta x$ (direction $x$ is perpendicular to the beam). This implies some uncertainty in momentum in the $x$ direction, so the beam diverges as it passes through the slit, because when the beam diverges the photons' momentum now has a component along $x$. Also the momentum needs to be conserved so the photons diverge symmetrically on both sides after passing.

But now consider **A:** if I simply put a card on beam's path such that the card blocks half the light beam (assuming the beam to have a circular cross-section, the card blocks a semicircle of the cross-section such that the card's light blocking edge $\perp$ $x$), will the light still diffract? If yes, how to explain it using Uncertainty principle? Will the diffraction be symmetric still?

This is another but similar problem: **B:** A laser can be diffracted off of a tightly stretched wire (tension in wire $\perp x$ direction). This is like the opposite of single slit...  How do I write $\Delta x$ here?

My guess: Is $\Delta x$ simply the width of the beam as it falls on the obstacle? That would mean in case A, $\Delta x$ would be the radius of cross-section of the beam. And in case B, the wire creates two beams by blocking a chunk of the the cross-section(wire's silhouette=two chords in the circular cross-section) $\therefore$ two segments of the cross-section move past the wire, so it's just a double slit diffraction and ($\Delta x$)s would simply be the height of these segments (maximum length perpendicular to the chord and touching the perimeter). Am I correct?

Comment: The uncertainty principle (UP) is a consequence of the fact that the far-field diffraction pattern can be written as a Fourier transform of the aperture function for the case of a small aperture. This is a special (approximate) case of a more general principle called the Huygens–Fresnel principle that states that every point on a wave front can be thought of as a spherical wave, and interference between these spherical waves yields the entire wave.  This is what would be used to generate the diffraction pattern off of an edge, and I don't think that you can apply the UP in this case.

Comment: @march here I'm only asking about the bending of the beam, not the diffraction pattern itself. The bending can definitely be explained using Uncertainty Pr.